# Sitecore xdb rebuild index fails at finishing stage

Tags: sitecore

we are using solr cloud with zookeeper for Sitecore 10.2 environment. We have created xdb and xdb_rebuild collections with aliases xdb_mainalias and xdb_rebuildalias respectively. When we trigger xdb rebuild, it moves all the way till finishing stage (95%) and fails there. When we dig the logs it says

```
[Error] An error occured during index rebuilding. There will be another attempt to check. The check interval after an error is 00:00:20. 
Sitecore.Xdb.Collection.Search.Solr.Failures.SolrRebuildCoreNotFoundException: Collection name for alias: [xdb_rebuild] not found in Zookeeper configuration.
   at Sitecore.Xdb.Collection.Search.Solr.SolrCloudRebuildHelper.<LoadCollectionNames>d__3.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.Xdb.Collection.Search.Solr.SolrCloudRebuildHelper.<SwapCores>d__1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.Xdb.Collection.Search.Solr.SolrIndexRebuilder.<CompleteRebuild>d__10.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.Xdb.Collection.Indexing.Rebuild.IndexRebuildFlow.<CompleteRebuild>d__28.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.Xdb.Collection.Indexing.Rebuild.IndexRebuildFlow.<RunRebuild>d__25.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.Xdb.Collection.Indexing.Rebuild.IndexRebuildFlow.RebuildStatusWatcher.<>c__DisplayClass5_0.<<Start>g__RunRebuildFlowCycle|0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Sitecore.Xdb.Collection.Indexing.Rebuild.TaskExtension.<ExecuteWithInterval>d__0.MoveNext()
```

We have already uploaded configs to zookeeper and created xdb collections using the same. Are move missing anything here?

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow! is the zookeeper still running? also, you might want to ask on [sitecore stackexchange](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/) or raise the issue to sitecore support. it is unfortunate that your problem is not [mcve] and common folks without sitecore can replicate.

Comment: also, make sure the config has the correct index names. you did mention `xdb_rebuild` on the problem description but not `testsite_xdb_rebuild` which mentioned in the error message.